# What is the equivalent of the rest procedure in SICP in MIT Scheme 9.2?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp, mit-scheme

I am on exercise 2.32 which presents the following code:

```
(define (subsets s)
  (if (null? s)
      (list nil)
      (let ((rest (subsets (cdr s))))
        (append rest (map <??> rest)))))
```

When I try to call the `rest` procedure in MIT Scheme 9.2 it doesn't recognize the procedure (there is a similar issue with `nil` in the book, which is replaced by `()` in modern Scheme). What is the equivalent `rest` procedure in modern Scheme? I don't believe it is `cdr` because `cdr` is used throughout the book.

Comment: There is no `rest` procedure in the code you give.

Comment: Note: In old Scheme code the operators related to pairs are: `cons`, `car`, and, `cdr`. Since it is possible to use `cons` to build other data structures than lists, one can not be sure that `(cdr xs)` is a list - unless one examines the context. In order to indicate that one is working on lists, some people use functions `first` and `rest` instead of `car` and `cdr`. The idea is that one knows that `(rest xs)` is a list - no matter what the context is. Finally: SICP was written years before this convention, so the SICP authors use `car` and `cdr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the exercise - `rest` is not a procedure, is a local variable that corresponds the the *rest* of the subsets (perhaps you should take a look at the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Lexical-Binding.html#Lexical-Binding) regarding `let`). This is what the book is asking:

```
(define (subsets set)
  (if (null? set)
      (list '())
      (let ((rest (subsets (cdr set))))
        (append rest
                (map (lambda (sets) (cons (car set) sets))
                     rest)))))
```

Comment: facepalm... thanks. The book hasn't covered let very much yet, I guess I didn't have it memorized yet.

Answer (score 4):

As @tfb points out, `rest` in this code is not a procedure, it is a locally-bound symbol.

Maybe you are misinterpreting an error message about `rest`; without seeing it, it is hard to say.